# How to extract a value from a multiple nested JSON file?

Tags: python, json

Due to my client's request, I can't share the full code. I have a JSON dictionary file that looks like this.

```json
{   'auto_learn': {'reports': {'lists': {'auto_learn_mode': 'off'}}},
    'log_messages': [],
    'nodes_visited': [   {   'conditions': '#realestate.lead || '
                                           '@property-action:move && '
                                           '#need_financing || '
                                           '#realestate.event.create || '
                                           '#realestate.event.change || '
                                           '#realestate.financing.investing && '
                                           '@property-action:offer || '
                                           '@financing-action:prequalify || '
                                           '@property-action:loan',
                             'dialog_node': 'node_5_1623641435645',
                             'title': 'Real Estate Lead'},
                         {   'conditions': '@property-action:sell',
                             'dialog_node': 'response_10_1623641502712'}]}
{   'auto_learn': {'reports': {'lists': {'auto_learn_mode': 'off'}}},
    'branch_exited': True,
    'branch_exited_reason': 'completed',
    'log_messages': [],
    'nodes_visited': [   {   'conditions': '#collect_name',
                             'dialog_node': 'node_9_1622935152333'}]}
{   'auto_learn': {'reports': {'lists': {'auto_learn_mode': 'off'}}},
    'log_messages': [],
    'nodes_visited': [   {   'conditions': 'welcome',
                             'dialog_node': 'Welcome',
                             'title': 'Welcome'}]}
{   'auto_learn': {'reports': {'lists': {'auto_learn_mode': 'off'}}},
    'log_messages': [],
    'nodes_visited': [   {   'conditions': 'welcome',
                             'dialog_node': 'Welcome',
                             'title': 'Welcome'}]}
{   'auto_learn': {'reports': {'lists': {'auto_learn_mode': 'off'}}},
    'branch_exited': True,
    'branch_exited_reason': 'completed',
    'log_messages': [],
    'nodes_visited': [   {   'conditions': '#collect_name',
                             'dialog_node': 'node_9_1622935152333'}]}
{   'auto_learn': {'reports': {'lists': {'auto_learn_mode': 'off'}}},
    'log_messages': [],
    'nodes_visited': [   {   'conditions': 'anything_else',
                             'dialog_node': 'node_2_1625358694233',
                             'title': 'Schedule Showing'}]}
{   'auto_learn': {'reports': {'lists': {'auto_learn_mode': 'off'}}},
    'log_messages': []}
{   'auto_learn': {'reports': {'lists': {'auto_learn_mode': 'off'}}},
    'branch_exited': True,
    'branch_exited_reason': 'fallback',
    'log_messages': [],
    'nodes_visited': [   {   'conditions': 'anything_else',
                             'dialog_node': 'Anything else',
                             'title': 'Anything else'}]}
{   'auto_learn': {'reports': {'lists': {'auto_learn_mode': 'off'}}},
    'log_messages': [],
    'nodes_visited': [   {   'dialog_node': 'node_1_1623624340072',
                             'title': 'Collect Contact Info - FN already '
                                      'captured'},
                         {   'conditions': '@email_address',
                             'dialog_node': 'handler_10_1623624340073'},
                         {   'dialog_node': 'node_1_1623624340072',
                             'title': 'Collect Contact Info - FN already '
                                      'captured'}]}
{   'auto_learn': {'reports': {'lists': {'auto_learn_mode': 'off'}}},
    'branch_exited': True,
    'branch_exited_reason': 'completed',
    'log_messages': [],
    'nodes_visited': [   {   'conditions': '#no || #nothing_else || '
                                           '#General_Ending',
                             'dialog_node': 'node_2_1623624340073'}]}
{   'auto_learn': {'reports': {'lists': {'auto_learn_mode': 'off'}}},
    'log_messages': [],
    'nodes_visited': [   {   'conditions': '#realestate.lead || '
                                           '@property-action:move && '
                                           '#need_financing || '
                                           '#realestate.event.create || '
                                           '#realestate.event.change || '
                                           '#realestate.financing.investing && '
                                           '@property-action:offer || '
                                           '@financing-action:prequalify || '
                                           '@property-action:loan',
                             'dialog_node': 'node_5_1623641435645',
                             'title': 'Real Estate Lead'},
                         {   'conditions': '@property-action:buy',
                             'dialog_node': 'response_8_1623641494324'}]}
{   'auto_learn': {'reports': {'lists': {'auto_learn_mode': 'off'}}},
    'log_messages': [],
    'nodes_visited': [   {   'conditions': 'anything_else',
                             'dialog_node': 'node_2_1625358694233',
                             'title': 'Schedule Showing'}]}
{   'auto_learn': {'reports': {'lists': {'auto_learn_mode': 'off'}}},
    'log_messages': [],
    'nodes_visited': [   {   'conditions': '#collect_address || '
                                           '@street_address || #unsure || #no',
                             'dialog_node': 'node_1_1625358766434',
                             'title': 'What Address?'},
                         {   'conditions': '#unsure || #no',
                             'dialog_node': 'response_3_1625358833887'},
                         {   'conditions': '#active_real_estate_agent || '
                                           '#office_staff',
                             'dialog_node': 'node_7_1623618470058'},
                         {   'conditions': "$customer_first_name != ''",
                             'dialog_node': 'response_2_1623623833612'},
                         {   'dialog_node': 'node_1_1623624340072',
                             'title': 'Collect Contact Info - FN already '
                                      'captured'},
                         {'dialog_node': 'handler_15_1623624340073'}]}
```

I can't extract the 'conditions' from the nodes_visited section because I keep getting a Key Error. To get this point I have the following code:

```py
debug = output['debug']
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
pp.pprint(debug)
```

So I thought the next step would be:

```py
nodes_visited = debug['nodes_visited']
conditions = nodes_visited['conditions']
```

But I get this error:

```py
File "C:/Users/Notebook/PycharmProjects/Jarvis/Watson.py", line 97, in <module>
    nodes_visited = output['nodes_visited']
KeyError: 'nodes_visited'
```

Nested dictionaries in JSONs are always hard for me. My end goal is to extract the value in condition if there is a value. For example, I want to pull "sell" from this condition.

```json
{   'conditions': '@property-action:sell',
```

Comment: Don't you see that `nodes_visited` is a list? You need to iterate over it or index it.

Comment: Could you kind of show clearly on the input and output you expect? Because in a few examples there's more than one condition.  Just wondering if you need only the first or all property-action items within conditions.

Answer (score 0):

`nodes_visited` is a list. You can use a list comprehension to get all the `conditions`.

```
debug = {   'auto_learn': {'reports': {'lists': {'auto_learn_mode': 'off'}}},
            'log_messages': [],
            'nodes_visited': [   {   'conditions': '#realestate.lead || '
                                     '@property-action:move && '
                                     '#need_financing || '
                                     '#realestate.event.create || '
                                     '#realestate.event.change || '
                                     '#realestate.financing.investing && '
                                     '@property-action:offer || '
                                     '@financing-action:prequalify || '
                                     '@property-action:loan',
                                     'dialog_node': 'node_5_1623641435645',
                                     'title': 'Real Estate Lead'},
                                 {   'conditions': '@property-action:sell',
                                     'dialog_node': 'response_10_1623641502712'}]}

conditions = [node['conditions'] for node in debug['nodes_visited'] if 'conditions' in node]
```

Comment: It printed this but then threw a Key Error.

['anything_else']
['anything_else']

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Notebook/PycharmProjects/Jarvis/Watson.py", line 97, in <module>
    conditions = [node['conditions'] for node in debug['nodes_visited'] if 'conditions' in node]

KeyError: 'nodes_visited'

Comment: Then `debug` isn't what you showed in the question. I've added my value of `debug`. I tested it and it worked.